# How to import cvs files to documentDb in a MAC?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Microsoft Azure DocumentDb data migration tool only has an .exe file, but i would need a .dmg which is not available in the Microsoft downloads site?

Comment: There is no support or tooling for data migrations when running on OS X. If you don't have access to a Windows installation, the best thing I can recommend is standing up an A0 VM with Windows Server on there, and then copy the relevant files over and migrate them that way.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Yannick, there is no current support for Mac.

Feel free to add a request at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb